# Problem with running a PyTorch code that uses multiprocessing to run on GPU

Tags: python, pytorch

I'd like to convert the [code](https://github.com/CORE-Robotics-Lab/MAGIC/tree/main) to run on GPU and Cuda. Currently, the code uses `torch.multiprocessing` module to run on multiple processors.

I read the tutorial in [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/save_load_across_devices.html), [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-up-and-run-cuda-operations-in-pytorch/) and [here](https://www.run.ai/guides/gpu-deep-learning/pytorch-gpu) and tried to send the [policy network](https://github.com/CORE-Robotics-Lab/MAGIC/blob/af608fda8e31d6c9acd5a63f8b55db1f0cd04f12/main.py#L162) to cude:

```
torch.set_default_tensor_type('torch.cuda.DoubleTensor')
device = torch.device("cuda")
policy_net.to(device)
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 339, in <module>
    run(args.num_epochs)
  File "main.py", line 263, in run
    s = trainer.train_batch(ep)
  File "/home/r/python_proj/phd/MAGIC/trainer.py", line 220, in train_batch
    batch, stat = self.run_batch(epoch)
  File "/home/r/python_proj/phd/MAGIC/trainer.py", line 209, in run_batch
    episode, episode_stat = self.get_episode(epoch)
  File "/home/r/python_proj/phd/MAGIC/trainer.py", line 50, in get_episode
    action_out, value, prev_hid = self.policy_net(x, info)
  File "/home/r/miniconda3/envs/marl_cav/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/r/python_proj/phd/MAGIC/magic.py", line 116, in forward
    encoded_obs = self.obs_encoder(obs)
  File "/home/r/miniconda3/envs/marl_cav/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/r/miniconda3/envs/marl_cav/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 93, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/home/r/miniconda3/envs/marl_cav/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1692, in linear
    output = input.matmul(weight.t())
RuntimeError: Tensor for 'out' is on CPU, Tensor for argument #1 'self' is on CPU, but expected them to be on GPU (while checking arguments for addmm)
```

Because I need to use pytorch < 2, I cannot use the following command `torch.set_default_device('cuda')`

I know it's tough to answer without seeing the entire code, but could someone please tell me (generally speaking) which parts of a Pytorch code need to be modified for it to run on a GPU? especially if that code uses concurrency

Comment: It's looking like the weights of your model are not moved to the gpu despite your `.to(device)` call. Maybe iterate through all the model parameters and move them by hand to the gpu.